# How to validate arangements(sequence) of <p> tag or text inside the div?

Tags: javascript

I want to check the arrangements to validate if it is in the right position after drag and drop event

```
<div class="container" id="con">
    <p class="draggable" draggable="true" id="p1">1</p>
    <p class="draggable" draggable="true" id="p2">2</p>
    <p class="draggable" draggable="true" id="p3">3</p>
    <p class="draggable" draggable="true" id="p4">4</p>
</div>
```

Comment: How do you define the "right position"?

Comment: right sequence 1 2 3 4

Comment: Get the div's p tags and check that their text content is 1, 2, 3, 4? What's the specific issue?

Comment: but as I dragged them the value doesnt change. p1 is still equal to 1 even if I drag it below the p4. the value is the same but the arrangement of p will will be 2341

Comment: Then you'd need to change the text. It's not clear what the requirement(s) or issue(s) actually are.

Comment: it is supposed to be for spelling. that is why i need to validate the right sequence of each p tag. c-a-t (1-2-3)

Comment: ... So I'll pretend the numbers here are supposed to be letters? Check them against whatever word you're trying to spell. I don't understand the underlying issue. If you drag them around do you *want* the text to change or not? If you don't, then what's the issue with comparing the extracted text against the word you're spelling?

Comment: they are changing. I already have code for it to change positions. i just want to know how to check if it is in the original position 1 2 3 4.

Comment: Check the ID order? Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. Questions need to include enough details to understand the problem, let alone be able to help.

Comment: sorry for that, english is not my first language. I just want to seek help

Comment: I understand :) It's important to describe the problem as best as possible, in the question itself. This means including a realistic example, what is wrong with the code, how you want it to behave, and what kinds of things happen (in this case) when a `<p>` is dragged and dropped. There are other language Stack Overflows as well (not *too* many) which may or may not be easier for you.

Comment: got it now, i just used the children,lastchild text content of the div hooray

Answer (score 1):

This is now my answer to my question. Got it

```
function myFunction() {
        var c = document.getElementById('con').children;
        var txt = "";
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
          txt = txt + c[i].lastChild.textContent  ;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope I get your meaning.
To detect the position, you can first set an array of the correct/valid sequence. Then, you may set a listener to trigger the function of validating the position on each drag or validate on submit.
For the function, you can loop throught the class, by getting the innerHTML of the class and comparing to the array you set earlier, you can identify if the sequence is correct or not.

```js
validate_item1();

function validate_item1(){
    let item1 = document.getElementsByClassName("item1");
    let trueSequence = ["A","E","R","O","P","L","A","N","E"];
    let result = true;
    for(let i=0;i<item1.length;i++){
        if(item1[i].innerHTML!=trueSequence[i]){
            result = false;
        }
    }
    
    if(result){
        alert("Sequence is correct");
    }else{
        alert("Incorrect sequence");
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div class="container" id="con">
    <p class="draggable item1" draggable="true">A</p>
    <p class="draggable item1" draggable="true">E</p>
    <p class="draggable item1" draggable="true">R</p>
    <p class="draggable item1" draggable="true">O</p>
    <p class="draggable item1" draggable="true">P</p>
    <p class="draggable item1" draggable="true">L</p>
    <p class="draggable item1" draggable="true">A</p>
    <p class="draggable item1" draggable="true">N</p>
    <p class="draggable item1" draggable="true">E</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```